# Android: Is it possible to take photo or video at the same time?

Tags: java, android, video, camera

I'm going to take photo or video in same screen and get result image or video.

Actually I don't want to build custom camera screen and I think there would be a way like through `intent`.

Please let me know the best way.

Comment: if you want to capture image at the time of video so as per my R&D it's possible with custom camera only. There is no intent which provide you both at the same time.

Comment: I see. Is there any other way or library?

Comment: you can check this library but in this yo have to do some code for capturing the image at the video.

https://github.com/memfis19/Annca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think there would be a way like through intent

Sorry, but there is no `ACTION_IMAGE_OR_VIDEO_CAPTURE_BUT_ONLY_USE_ONE_SCREEN_K_THX_BYE` action, or anything like that, in the Android SDK. :-)

> Is there any other way or library?

There are a variety of [camera libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/141?sort=created). Only some support video (e.g., CameraKit-Android).